# ExtJs component extend issue

Tags: javascript, extjs

I extend Ext.form.FormPanel. It's contains `first panel` with buttons and `second panel` which render by button click. Like on the picture:

[image]

But `second panel's` items it's variable i give it to me extended FormPanel when create this like this:

```
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({...});]
sote.load({params:{....}});

var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
//**config**//
store:store
}); 

var usersPanel = new myapp.StandartForm({
//**some config**//
secondPanelItems:[grid,{field1},{filed2...}]

});
```

So `grid` created only once when i create my extended FormPanel.  How can i create it every time when the second panel shows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use xtype. so grid will be created each time you instantiate it (edit: add store as xtype)

```
var usersPanel = new myapp.StandartForm({
    //**some config**//
    secondPanelItems:[{
        xtype: 'grid',
        //**grid config**//
        store: {
            xtype: 'jsonstore',
            autoLoad: true,
            // other store attr
            baseParams: {...}
        }
    },{field1},{filed2...}]
});
```

Comment: but what about store? It's loaded just once. I mean that i can create it inside grid but for load data i gonna send POST parameters on server. For this i use load() method. Its possible to do with `autoLoad`?

Comment: I'm not sure. but you want to create the store with xtype, like the grid, you can define baseParams. It will be use when loading data. But I never use so you have to test.

Comment: `baseParams` works. But anyway i need reload store. But still dont know how to do this like in my question.

Comment: if you create the store with xtype it will not reload?

Comment: oh sorry i was created store inside grid use `new Ext.data...`. Thank your code work.